# Autodesk Platform services refresh power bi

Tags: powerbi, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am pulling data into my power bi report with Autodesk power bi connector data exchange, but I cannot auto-renew from the power bi web service, it gives an error. Can you help with this? I think data exchange does not support automatic renewals.

I wanted to automatically refresh my Power BI report, but it gave an error in the power BI web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Auto-refresh feature is not available yet and is known limitation till the connector is certified by Microsoft. Hope it helps!

[Documentation Link](https://help.autodesk.com/view/DATAEXCHANGE/ENU/?guid=pwrbi-known-limitations)